# ImportError: No module named bcrypt

Tags: python, flask, bcrypt

I am trying to have my Python application encrypt passwords before storing them in an SQLite3 table.I have installed bcrypt on my Flask VirtualEnvironment. However, whenever i run my  script i get the error:

```
File "./run.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/home/test/app/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from app import views
  File "/home/test/app/views.py", line 8, in <module>
    from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
  File "/home/test/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_bcrypt.py", line 27, in <module>
    raise e
ImportError: No module named bcrypt
```

line 8 on views.py looks like this:

```
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
```

What can i be possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: I guess you are in linux environment. Can you install apt install python-dev for adding `py-bcrypt` into python development headers

Comment: Make sure that your venv is active and `bcrypt` is importable from the interactive interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure you're installing bcrypt under your venv. first source your venv setup file and check by `which pip` if pip points to the right location, then do pip install bcrypt (not sure what the library is exactly called - could be py-bcypt as said above).

Comment: This answers my question. Installing `py-bycrypt` in the virtualenv solved the problem

Answer (score 8):

`pip install py-bcrypt --user` there is a typo in comment above.

Comment: Thanks @michalxo this worked for me: `pip3 install py-bcrypt`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `bcrypt`.

1. You can use :

`pip install bcrypt`

2. Or you can use `flask_bcrypt`:

`pip install flask-bcrypt` or `pip install flask_bcrypt`

Then all you need is to import either one of them.